# Can I have more than one public keys saved in one selector for dkim?

Tags: domain-name-system, email, email-server, dkim, e-mailrelay

The question is easy to understand, but it might be confusing. I understand that I can host multiple selectors for a DKIM record, but just out of curiosity, can I have multiple keys per selector in a DKIM TXT record?

Comment: For what? ......

Comment: @NikitaKipriyanov Please elaborate 'For what?'.

Comment: I wanted you to elaborate :) Why would you want to have multiple keys in one entry?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In 2024, one key per entry, if I understood the RFC correctly.

If you desire to obtain more precise information, RFC6376 (https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6376) may prove to be of interest to you.

Comment: On top of that, having multiple keys per selector doesn't make any sense at all.

Comment: @djdomi I got this doubt from reading the RFC itself in section 3.2 'Tag=Value Lists' it is stated that 'Values are a series of strings containing .......'; I got the doubt from 'series' part of the sentence.

Comment: It's usually meant that one selector includes one value per x=y value.which means it has be at least some included that it works. But it does not mean, that one selector can host multiple one. For that it was never designed before. It should be noted that in cases where multiple keys are present, not all keys would be taken into consideration due most of the Application will assume only one Key per DNS-Entry. And to be more clear, we spoke about the key itself and not the configuration items.